# Unable to locate tools.jar Fedora

Tags: android, python, ant

I'm trying to compile my python game to run on android using PGS4A and I'm getting this error

```
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-      1.7.0.60-2.4.7.0.fc20.x86_64/lib/tools.jar
```

There are a bunch of solutions for this on Windows but I can't find one for fedora.

I have the /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.7.0.fc20.x86_64/ but nothing else

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you are using the Java that comes packaged with Fedora (some version of OpenJDK) you probably need to install the appropriate `-devel` package.

Here's an example of what you would do on my Fedora 20 workstation:

```
$ rpm -qa|grep openjdk
java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless-1.7.0.60-2.4.7.0.fc20.x86_64
java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.7.0.fc20.x86_64
$ sudo yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel
...
```

The first command tells me what Java I'm using (1.7.0, since 1.8.0 is another option) and the second command asks it to install the development libraries, which includes tools.jar, among other things.

But I should add that my `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.7.0.fc20.x86_64` directory does contain a few things:

```
-r--r--r--. 1 root root 172252 Apr 16 02:58 THIRD_PARTY_README
-r--r--r--. 1 root root  19263 Apr 16 02:58 LICENSE
-r--r--r--. 1 root root   1503 Apr 16 02:58 ASSEMBLY_EXCEPTION
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root   4096 Apr 20 19:09 jre-abrt
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root   4096 Apr 20 19:09 jre
```

Comment: Correct, the -devel package is what I needed to run Android Studio. It contains tools.jar among other things.